# Order an array issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

Okay, so I created a gradebook of sorts. You add in your first and last name, and the grade, and it adds it to the table (It works when I run on Chrome, but not on jsfiddle for some reason. That's not the issue)

https://jsfiddle.net/bhLhayar/

The problem I have is with the sorting. My radio buttons say "not defined" but I thought I had them defined in my JS. Advice please? XD

```
function sortby(what){
if(what == 'firstN'){studentdata.sortbyfirstSet();}
if(what == 'lastN'){studentdata.sortbylastSet();}
if(what == 'gradeUp'){studentdata.sortbygradeSetUp();}
if(what == 'gradeDown'){studentdata.sortbygradeSetDown();}
updatetable()
}
```

Here is the code where I think I went wrong?. Has to do with this:

```
sortbyFirstSet(){
        this.data.sort(function (one, two){
            if(one.firstName > two.firstName){return 1}
            if(one.firstName < two.firstName){return -1}
            if(one.firstName == two.firstName){return 0}
        });
    }
    sortbylastSet(){
        this.data.sort(function (one, two){
            if(one.lastName > two.lastName){return 1}
            if(one.lastName < two.lastName){return -1}
            if(one.lastName == two.lastName){return 0}
        });
    }
    sortbygradeSetUp(){
        this.data.sort(function (one, two){
            if(one.finalGrade > two.finalGrade){return 1}
            if(one.finalGrade < two.finalGrade){return -1}
            if(one.finalGrade == two.finalGrade){return 0}
        });
    }
  sortbygradeSetDown(){
    this.data.sort(function (one, two){
      if(one.finalGrade < two.finalGrade){return 1}
      if(one.finalGrade > two.finalGrade){return -1}
      if(one.finalGrade == two.finalGrade){return 0}
    });
  }
```

Comment: WHat radio buttons do you speak of? I do not see any HTML code at all.

Comment: I placed a link for jsfiddle.net

Comment: In the jsFiddle at least, it appears that none of the `onclick=""` attributes are working correctly. Using `.addEventListener` works for at least the `Info Submit` button.

Comment: Thank you, but submitting the information isn't the problem I have. It works in a regular browser, so jsfiddle isn't making me sweat much. Mostly focused on the radio buttons not doing what they should. I'm stumped. Could be something simple.. haha

Comment: Also, in the `onclick=""` attributes for the radio buttons, you try to pass in an undefined variable instead of a string. i.e. : `onclick="sortby(gradeUp)"` instead of: `onclick="sortby('gradeUp')"`

Comment: Tom Burris: Thank you, that was EXACTLY my issue. Something simple, like I said.. 
Dang I need some sleep....

Comment: @JHillman I see a trend of not accepting answers. Can you accept them once you get what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be passing in a string as a variable. Try onclick="sortby('lastN')" etc. instead.

And you don't have an updatetable function. Perhaps you wanted to call updateGradebook()?

**Update**
One more thing, your first call to the sort method is misspelled. Should be sortbyFirstSet

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: @TomBurris it seems to be since the value he is passing into the method is undefined?

Comment: Did you test to see if that solves the issue? Unfortunately it does not. There are quite a few issues with this script and an answer should address all of them.

Comment: @TomBurris it solves the error he sees, which is due to that. And that is the question I believe.

Comment: Now the answer is much more filled out and can be considered viable.

Comment: @TomBurris the question was not to fix all of the code but to identify the reason for the "not defined" error.

Comment: Thank you both for helping me out with this. I used the first suggestion to fix my simple error. Then I discovered the next two, which I ended up fixing on my own before I checked this site again.
Also, @Hosney, I'm sorry about not accepting answers. I'm still relatively new to the site. Won't be an issue again. :]

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your onclick code on radio buttons to sortby('firstN') from sortby(firstN). Also it seems that studentdata is an array and and you are trying to call the sortby functions using that.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.